# Group of finite ideles

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, definition

A simple question:

> If $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ denotes the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{C}$ then what is the definition of the group of *finite* ideles of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$?

Many thanks.

Comment: Where did you find this term in use? Are there contexts or references?

Comment: I first came across this term in Frohlich's book 'Classgroups and Hermitian Modules' and have seen in several papers in number theory.

Comment: I see; this is the first time I see it. Sounds interesting. :)

Comment: Frohlich doesn't define this term in his book?  That seems strange.

Comment: @Pete L. Clark  You are right- I've found the definition of the term in Frohlich's book on page 75 (now that I've managed to obtain it)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a reference:
See page 102 of [this paper](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/JTNB/JTNB_1992__4_1/JTNB_1992__4_1_97_0/JTNB_1992__4_1_97_0.pdf).

Comment: And for the finite part I suppose you can just leave off $\mathbb{R}^\times$.

Comment: In other words, take the direct limit.